# Debugging in Netbeans For loop

Tags: netbeans

Can anyone help me in debugging a for loop in netbeans. The issue is that i don't want to go through all the iterations of the loop but only the 7th iteration and the last iteration. How can i do this??

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You can set a *conditional* breakpoint in the first line *inside* the loop.

To define a conditional breakpoint, first create a regular one.

Then right click on the little red square in the left margin and choose "Breakpoint -> Properties".

Enable the conditions checkbox and add the condition `i == 5` in there (assuming your loop index variable is named i)